# Eliminate space after section heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I have set the spacing after `subsubsection` to `1sp`, but there is still an appreciable space between the heading and the text (approx `1ex`). Obviously, I can't set a negative value, and I don't want to manually create a negative space at the start of every `subsubsection`.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Is there a length variable that I should be setting?

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {1.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-0em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@ }%
                                           {-1.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                           {1sp \@minus 1ex}%
                                           {\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }}
\makeatother
\subsubsection*{Blah}
This text is 1ex from the heading blah, but I would like it to be hard up 
against the heading (but not on the same line)
\end{document}
```

I need to be able to have some headings which have some space, and some which have none, so I can't use a package which simply affects the whole document.

Comment: If you want to control manually which ones have headings and which don't, just define different commands; say \subsubsectionA and subsubsectionB. If you want the spacing to be chosen automatically, you need to give us more details.

Comment: @Hector I don't know what you mean. The problem is, and I think this is clear, how to eliminate the `1ex` space that remains after setting the vertical spacing to `1sp` in the `subsubsection` command.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use something like  \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

Comment: @Hector Because I don't want **all** titles to be compact.

Comment: I am not sure if something like this is what you want: `\renewcommand\subsubsection{\offinterlineskip\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@ }
                                           {-1.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
                                           {1sp \@minus 1ex}
                                           {\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Probably that is what I want. I didn't know about `\offinterlineskip`. Go ahead and post that as an answer with a description of what it does, and I'll vote it up. Update: testing shows that that still leaves a gap (albeit slightly smaller). Sorry.

Comment: @Marcin please see my updated answer with a new approach; I am not sure, however, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want (or why do you want it), but you can use `\nointerlineskip` and then annihilate the effect of `\lineskip`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
  {1.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-0em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@ }%
  {-1.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1sp \@minus 0ex\nointerlineskip\vspace{-\lineskip}}%
  {\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }}
\makeatother

\subsubsection*{Blah}
This text is 1ex from the heading blah, but I would like it to be hard up 
against the heading (but not on the same line)

\end{document}
```

An some text of the resulting document zoomed at 400% to see the resulting heading and following text:

[image]

On a side note, setting `\parskip` and `\parindent` to `0pt` might not be a good idea (the [`l2tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu) document contains some details).

Answer (score 5):

Including `\usepackage{titlesec}` (without any package parameters) enables the following command:

```
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{1.0ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{-\parskip}
```

The final `{-\parskip}` eliminates the `1ex` gap.

Note that this will have no effect if the `\subsubsection` is renewed in the document - one has to pick one or the other.

Comment: Found out this works with at least the `uppercase` option, so will probably work with everything else!