# Different vertical spacing (parskip) between concurrent section titles and paragraphs

Tags: spacing, sectioning, paragraphs, koma-script, titlesec

I'm trying to remove the spacing between section headings, but maintain the paragraph to section heading spacing.

Even though I set `titlespacing` before and after to `*0`, there is still spacing - quite a bit more in the case of `\section`.

I've tried a number of things, getting close with setting `titlespacing{\<eachone>}{*0}{-5.8pt}`, but it's not complete and has a number of problems.  Removes vertical space to the first paragraph and section still has more space than expected.

Here's what I have:

[image]

And what I'm looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper,asymmetric,left=108pt,right=54pt,top=41pt,bottom=41pt,headsep=13pt,headheight=14pt,footskip=23pt,marginparwidth=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact,explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
%
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont}
%
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
%
\newlength\titlemarginwidth
\setlength\titlemarginwidth{54pt}
%
\newcommand\boxedsection[6]{{%
  \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{#2}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, inner ysep=0.7ex, node distance=0]%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text width=\titlemarginwidth-\columnsep-1pt,color=#3] at (0,0) (numnode) {\vphantom{yZ}\hspace{1ex}#6};%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text width=\textwidth-.5pt] at ($(numnode.base east)+(\columnsep,0)$) (textnode) {\vphantom{yZ}#1};%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}%
      \fill[color=#4] (0,0|-numnode.north) rectangle (numnode.south east|-textnode.south east);%
      \draw[#5,semithick] (0,0|-numnode.north) -- (textnode.north east);%
      \draw[#5,semithick] (0,0|-textnode.south west) -- (textnode.south east);%
    \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-0.7\titlemarginwidth}{50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\emph{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}%
  {0em}%
  {\emph{#1}}%
%
\titlespacing*{\section}{-\titlemarginwidth}{*0}{*0}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\setstretch{1}}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}{section}{white}{black}{black}{\thesection}}%
%
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{*0}{*0}
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
  {\setstretch{1}}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}{subsection}{black}{gray!30}{black}{\thesubsection}}%
%
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{*0}{*0}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]
  {\setstretch{1}}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}{subsubsection}{black}{white}{black}{\thesubsubsection}}%
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subection}
\subsubsection{Subsubection}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

*[Possibly related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65033/eliminate-space-after-section-heading)*

Comment: I am confused.  Are we allowed to wager more reputation than our balance, or is Mr. Clark attempting to set a coveted stackexchange record to be the first user with negative reputation?

Comment: The bounty points have already been deducted from his reputation, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties

Answer (score 12):

COMMENTS ON LATEST EDIT:

In response to Mr. Clark's stipulation that he didn't like the `\vskip`s, those have been successfully removed.  Further, all spacings are issued through the `titlesec` package and are now specified in terms of `\baselineskip`, which should provide more flexigility for fontsize changes.  Significant changes in this edit were several.  First, changing the titlesec format from "display" to "hang" accomplished a great deal.  However, the issue of `\lineskiplimit` proved to be decisive.  The `\boxedsection` command created by Jeff was of a size not close to an even multiple of `\baselineskip` and so LaTeX kept adding a line to correct a perceived problem.  Setting the line-skip-limit to a more negative value resolved the issue.  And it allowed me to use just the `titlesec` parameters to achieve the result, without any vspaces.

Nonetheless, there remained the issue of glue, to which I alluded in one of the comments.  I was largely able to remedy it by setting `\parskip` to 0 and setting `\textfloatsep` so that it couldn't grow (I'm not wholly sure I'm using that command properly). However, a super-zoom on the flushed section headings can still occasionally perceive some glue-gap.
Maybe there's another glue parameter that can help.

COMMENTS ON AN EARLIER EDIT:

In response to the comment that there probably needs to be no separate commands used for the flushed sub- and subsub-section headings, I have remedied that problem, with one proviso.  The method works by counting how many `\par`s have been issued after the higher-level section invocation.  It starts by assuming you have a flush-heading sub*section.  Then it starts counting `\pars`.  Once it reaches a critical number, it concludes that you have added text to the section , and changes the `\sub*section` heading for the next lower heading level.  Therefore, the user must be consistent in how they add text to a section.  Currently, the triggers are set up for the following structure

```
\section{name}
<blank line>
text
<blank line>
\subsection{name}
<blank line>
text
<blank line>
\subsubsection{name}
```

or for flush headings

```
\section{name}
<blank line>
\subsection{name}
<blank line>
\subsubsection{name}
```

Thus, there remains the requirement for the user to type his section headings consistently.  And because of the feature of texexchange to squeeze blank lines out of listings, the needed blank lines in the body do not show up in the below listing.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper,asymmetric,left=108pt,right=54pt,top=41pt,bottom=41pt,headsep=13pt,headheight=14pt,footskip=23pt,marginparwidth=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact,explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
%
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont}
%
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
%
\newlength\titlemarginwidth
\setlength\titlemarginwidth{54pt}
%
\newcommand\boxedsection[6]{{%
  \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{#2}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, inner ysep=0.7ex, node distance=0]%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text
width=\titlemarginwidth-\columnsep-1pt,color=#3] at (0,0) (numnode)
{\vphantom{yZ}\hspace{1ex}#6};%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text width=\textwidth-.5pt] at
($(numnode.base east)+(\columnsep,0)$) (textnode) {\vphantom{yZ}#1};%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}%
      \fill[color=#4] (0,0|-numnode.north) rectangle (numnode.south
east|-textnode.south east);%
      \draw[#5,semithick] (0,0|-numnode.north) -- (textnode.north
east);%
      \draw[#5,semithick] (0,0|-textnode.south west) -- (textnode.south
east);%
    \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
\newcommand\flushboxedsection[6]{{%
  \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{#2}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0, inner ysep=0.7ex, node distance=0]%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text
width=\titlemarginwidth-\columnsep-1pt,color=#3] at (0,0) (numnode)
{\vphantom{yZ}\hspace{1ex}#6};%
    \node[anchor=base west,rectangle,text width=\textwidth-.5pt] at
($(numnode.base east)+(\columnsep,0)$) (textnode) {\vphantom{yZ}#1};%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}%
      \fill[color=#4] (0,0|-numnode.north) rectangle (numnode.south
east|-textnode.south east);%
      \draw[#5,semithick] (0,0|-textnode.south west) -- (textnode.south
east);%
    \end{pgfonlayer}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}%
%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{-0.7\titlemarginwidth}{50pt}{40pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
  {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\emph{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}%
  {0em}%
  {\emph{#1}}%

\titlespacing*{\section}{-\titlemarginwidth}{.6\baselineskip}{*0}%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
  {\setstretch{1.6}}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}{section}{white}{black}{black}{\thesection}%
}

\def\tsubsectionbox{%
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{.8\baselineskip}{*0}%
  \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]%
    {}%
    {}{0pt}{%
  \boxedsection{##1}{subsection}{black}{gray!30}{black}{\thesubsection}}%
}
%
\def\fsubsectionbox{%
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{*0}{.2\baselineskip}%
  \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]%
    {\setstretch{1.38}}%
    {}{0pt}{%
  \flushboxedsection{##1}{subsection}{black}{gray!30}{black}{\thesubsection}}%
}
%
\newcounter{subparcounter}
\let\savesection\section
\def\section{\fsubsectionbox\setcounter{subparcounter}{0}\savesection}
%
\def\tsubsubsectionbox{%
  \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{.8\baselineskip}{*0}%
  \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]%
    {}%
    {}{0pt}{%
  \boxedsection{##1}{subsubsection}{black}{white}{black}{\thesubsubsection}}%
}
%
\def\fsubsubsectionbox{%
  \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-\titlemarginwidth}{*0}{0\baselineskip}%
  \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]%
    {\setstretch{1.1}}%
    {}{0pt}{%
  \flushboxedsection{##1}{subsubsection}{black}{white}{black}{\thesubsubsection}}%
}
%
\newcounter{subsubparcounter}
\let\savesubsection\subsection
\def\subsection{\fsubsubsectionbox\setcounter{subsubparcounter}{0}%
  \savesubsection}
%
\let\savepar\par
\def\par{%
  \savepar%
  \addtocounter{subsubparcounter}{1}%
  \addtocounter{subparcounter}{1}%
  \ifthenelse{5 = \value{subsubparcounter}}%
  {\tsubsubsectionbox}%
  {}%
  \ifthenelse{5 = \value{subparcounter}}%
  {\tsubsectionbox}%
  {}%
}%
%
% SEE: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf
\lineskiplimit = -12pt % <--MAY NEED TO BE MADE MORE NEGATIVE!
\parskip 0ex
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{20pt plus 0pt minus 4pt}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Section}

\lipsum[2]

text

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

Text

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[2]

text

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

Text

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\lipsum[2]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[2]

text

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

Text

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

Text

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I expect @Jeffrey will not like it that much, as one has to _manually_ tell TeX, where it should not insert the free space after the headline by using `
\flush(sub)*section{title}` instead of `\(sub)*section{title}`. But apart from that it is a nice solution =)

Comment: @DominikusK.  Resolved, with a proviso.

Comment: Interesting solution.  The hard-coded negative \vspace is a problem.  As in your screenshot, 1.2.1 gray fill overlaps (confirmed locally) the preceding \section.  Any change in font, font size, or spacing in the tikz title, requires manual tweaking.

Comment: I guess I really don't understand why when I set titlespacing ...*0, there is still space.

Comment: @JeffreyClark I don't understand titlesec either, but there is a rigidchapters package option (as opposed to the default rubberchapters option).  Don't know if it applies to things other than "chapters", but it might be a factor.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You should know, that KOMA-Script and `titlesec` are not fully compatible. Markus Kohm, the KOMA-Script developer, uttered about this several times, alas only in German, see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/incompatibilities-between-koma-script-and-titlesec). So problems can occur.

Comment: @JeffreyClark Please read comment above. ^^

Comment: @JeffreyClark One of the problems I see (I think) is that one will always come out of sectioning mode (whatever that means), however briefly, between calls to `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. Thus, I'm thinking there will always be some LaTeX glue between those entities. As you pointed out re: my approach, there was either a tiny gap or overlap between supposedly flush items. I'm thinking with any approach that is forced to come out of sectioning mode between `\sub*section` invocations, that slight glue-induced variations will be a problem (unless colorbars are removed/revised)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides : I was hoping to know who pushed me over the 1000pt in 30 days limit.  Appreciate the upvote.