# Strict \titlespacing without glue

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

### Problem Description

TeX seems to *adjust the vertical space* in a 2-column document, even though I have specified that no stretching or shrinking is to occur using \titlespacing. A short visualization is given under (a) in the Figure below:

[image: (a) Minimal Working Example showing that \titlespacing..{12pt}{0pt} is not applied (b) Real case in which this occurs, not included as source.]

Even though I specify e.g. `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{**12pt**}{**0pt**}`, there seems to be a vertical layout that will stretch out the spacing between headings, which is unacceptable, at least for the specific conference style I have to fulfill.

### Question

Can I get rid of this "vertical justification"? Any possible explanations are more than welcome. Here is my MWE that reproduces the behaviour (Note: I am using xelatex, but using latex yields the same behaviour):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{multicol}
% ----important----
\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt} 
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt}
% -----------------
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \title{Foo Bar 2013: A personal journey through a typographic nightmare.}
  \author{Waldorf A. and Stattler B.}
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
  this would in fact be longer, thus we make a space here
  \vspace{10cm}
  \end{abstract}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \section*{first order heading}
  All that is gold does not glitter. Not all those who wander are lost. The old that is     
  strong does not wither.
  \section*{first order heading}
  \subsection*{second order heading}
  Deep roots are not reached by the frost.  
  \section*{first order heading}
  \subsection*{second order heading}
  From the ashes a fire shall be woken. A light from the shadows shall spring. Renewed 
  shall be blade that was broken. The crownless again shall be king.
  \section*{first order heading}
  \subsection*{second order heading}
  \subsubsection*{third order heading}
  Not all that have fallen are vanquished. A king may yet be without crown. A blade 
  that was broken be brandished. 
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

### References

I have seen questions that deal with the topic, but none that really helped:

- [What is Glue Stretching](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64756/what-is-glue-stretching) says that "any glue is composed by a fixed part, a stretchable part and a shrinkable part. Each of these parts can be zero ... expressed via `<fixed part> plus <stretchable part> minus <shrinkable part>`. Tried that, but no luck - problem persists.
- Read somewhere (I don't exactly recall where, to my shame!) that you should try specifying e.g. -0 as "space after", i.e. `\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{-0}`. No luck.

Comment: Oh, and forgot: under (b) in the above Figure you can see a full-fledged layout, with red bars to indicate where the spacing is "wrong". Just for completeness.

Comment: See a related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/different-vertical-spacing-parskip-between-concurrent-section-titles-and-parag/101944#101944 for issues on glue when using the `titlesec` package.

Comment: See also http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Steven B. Segletes, that totally answered the question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Steven B. Segletes and his pointers in the comments above, I have found a way and want to share it here:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
```

and maybe also

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}
```

yielded the intended (and arguably boring) layout:

[image: no glue, yipee]

thank you!