# Vertical space between 2 subsequent headers (of chapters, sections, etc)

Tags: spacing, sectioning, documentclass-writing

I'm writing a LaTeX class for my bachelor's thesis. My university's standard says that there should be a space after headers:

- 2cm if there's text after the header
- 1.3cm if there's another header after it (for example, subsequent section and subsection headers).

For now I've set 2cm space after all headers (in the class file) and adding `\vspace{-7mm}` between subsequent headers (manually, in the document). Is there a way to make it automatically, i.e. some kind of "conditional spacing" if the last command was a header?

Comment: Hi Valeriy, and welcome to the site!

Comment: My first try would be: Set the default space to `13mm`, and look into the code that prevents the first paragraph from indenting; then add another `7mm` space there.

Comment: A point of terminology: you are talking about heads (chapter, section, etc...), not headers (the line that appears at the top of each page, like the footers that appear at the bottom of each page).

Comment: It's not clear to me what a useful answer would look like: do you want to know how to detect this case so you can go off and implement your own code for heads?  Or do you want to know how to modify an existing class file to do what you want?  If the latter, which class file are you working with?

Comment: As Charles Stewart said, it depends on what class/method you are trying.  If, for example, you are using the titlesec package, here was a questiont that looked at that issue:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/different-vertical-spacing-parskip-between-concurrent-section-titles-and-parag/101944#101944

Comment: To jmc: thanks; looks like a good idea, but will it work if a section starts with a table\float\whatever? It could appear in an appendix.

Comment: To Charles: I'm looking for "own code for heads", something like `\renewcommand{\chapter}{...}` which will add the spaces depending on the previous occurred command. Is that possible?

Comment: @ValeriyStreltsov, the only thing I can then think of is putting a `tikzmark` in every head, and let the next head check what the distance is to the previous head. But I think this is very demanding on resources…

Comment: With no clarification, this is 'unclear' as it stands.