# Spacing between titles depending existence of subsection

Tags: spacing, titlesec

By normative control standarts, spacing between title of a section and one of a subsection (similarly for subsection/subsubsection) must have length 0.8 cm and spacing between any title and a text must have length 1.5 cm.

I know how to set spacing between a title and a text:

```
\titlespacing{command}{left}{before}{after}
```

But how i can change the spacing if title of subsection exists? I tried to use various commands, but the spacing is always equal `secspacing<after>` or `secspacing<after>+subsecspacing<before>`.

Comment: If there is some consistency in your coding, one might be able to work around your problem. That is, one could check for usages of `\section[*][..]{...}<token>` and evaluate whether `<token>` is `\subsection` and condition accordingly about what space to use.

Comment: This question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/different-vertical-spacing-parskip-between-concurrent-section-titles-and-parag, may be relevant.