# parskip and title spacing conflict

Tags: spacing, titlesec, parskip

#### Issue

I am trying to set spacing between paragraphs using `\parskip` but it also affects section titles and "breaks" formatting.

#### Question

How can I set up a skip between paragraphs without having it influence section formating?

#### Bonus question

The frame around the title in the screenshot without `parksip` is closer to the top than to the bottom of the text. Why is that and how can I fix it?

#### Demo

1. Default

[image: default]

2. With `parskip`

[image: parskip]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\section}
  [frame]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\quad \Large \bfseries \Roman{section}. \enskip \MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:section-1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[Relevant thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101545/different-vertical-spacing-parskip-between-concurrent-section-titles-and-parag)

Comment: using the parskip package instead of setting parskip directly will do some of this, but better is to use a class designed for setting with non zero paragraph skip, so the headings already account for this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle While it does look nicer it does not completely fix my issue. It also cannot be customized. 
Could you please explain to me how one would go about creating such a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Proposed solution

Following the advice of @DavidCarlisle, I removed the custom settings on `parskip` and simply let the [`parskip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package manage the basic spacing.

Since I still wanted to customize some things, I used the following settings using the [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to tailor it to my needs:

```
\titlespacing*{\section}      {0em}{.75em}{.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}   {0em}{.50em}{.25em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0em}{.50em}{.25em}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}    {0em}{.25em}{.25em}
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\titlespacing*{\section}      {0em}{.75em}{.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}   {0em}{.50em}{.25em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0em}{.50em}{.25em}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}    {0em}{.25em}{.25em}
\titleformat{\section}
  [frame]
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\quad \Large \bfseries \Roman{section}. \enskip \MakeUppercase}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:section-1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

#### Demo

[image]