# How do I move the first line of every paragraph up with everypar and vspace?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to modify https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399944/2066 to adjust the spacing after sections headings which are not immediately followed by other section headings.  However, if I replace the `\hrule\vspace{1ex}` with `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` in that answer, using the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
    \@nobreakfalse
    \clubpenalty \@M
    \if@afterindent \else
                    {\setbox\z@\lastbox
                      \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
                    }%
                    \fi
                    \else
                    \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
                    \everypar{}%
                    \fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]


\section{Test}

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]


\section{Test}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Sub Test}

\section[optional]{Test}
\subsection[optional]{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]

\section{blblblb}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I get the very ugly

[image]

How do I get the first line of the paragraph to be moved up, rather than the second line?

Comment: My experiments **always** used \@afterindentfalse.  Not sure what \if@afterindent was intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the negative space after the first line of the paragraph, you need to back out of horizontal mode with `\par` to add the negative space before the first line, but then take account that the indentation suppression needs to be re-done for the "real" paragraph.

So this does what is intended although hooking into the after-indent test is only a very loose approximation to testing for a following section head so this will not work in all cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
    \@nobreakfalse
    \clubpenalty \@M
    \if@afterindent \else
                    {\setbox\z@\lastbox
                      \par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\noindent
                    }%
                    \fi
                    \else
                    \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
                    \everypar{}%
                    \fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]


\section{Test}

\subsection{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]


\section{Test}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Sub Test}

\section[optional]{Test}
\subsection[optional]{Sub Test}
\lipsum[4]

\section{blblblb}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted